# T-SQL Selecting distinct rows using locking table

Tags: sql, multithreading, entity-framework, t-sql, locking

I have a payment system and I have a problem. I will try to provide a minimal example reproducing it. Access to database is implemented using Entity Framework 6 but it seems to be not important in this question.

There is a table `Payments (ID IDENTITY (1,1) bigint, Status int)` with all payments in system including pending and completed.

An ASP.NET application inserts many payments in this table with `Status = 1 (Pending)`.

I have a Windows-service application called "Pending processor" which runs several (from 10 to 30) threads (workers). 
Every worker executes the same code in an infinite loop: **it takes the next pending payment, processes it and saves it back to the database**.

```
while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var payment = _paymentsRepository.GetNextPending();
    payment = _paymentProcessor.Process(payment);
    _paymentsRepository.Update(payment);
}
```

Now, I have encountered a problem: **several threads pick up the same payment and process it several times**. As result, we have an unhappy user with lost money.

I decided to fix this problem using locking table `PaymentLocks (ID bigint UNIQUE)`. Now, **I insert payment ID to a locking table, process this payment and remove this ID from a locking table.

If this payment is already being processed by another thread, then insert fails due to unique constraint and method returns null. Then, this thread doesn't process anything and continues it's cycle**.

```
while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var payment = _paymentsRepository.GetNextPendingAndAcquireLock();
    if (payment != null) _paymentProcessor.Process(payment);
    _paymentsRepository.UpdateAndReleaseLock(payment);
}

// ...

public Payment GetNextPendingAndAcquireLock()
{
    try 
    {
        string query = @"
    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRAN
        DECLARE @paymentId bigint;

        SET @paymentId = (SELECT TOP 1 p.Id
        FROM [dbo].[Payments] p 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PaymentLocks] pl 
        ON p.Id = pl.PaymentId 
        WHERE pl.PaymentId IS NULL);

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[PaymentLocks] ([PaymentId]) VALUES (@paymentId);

        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Payments] WHERE [Id] = @paymentId;
      COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH";

        return _dbContext.Payments.SqlQuery(query).Single();
    }
    catch (EntityCommandExecutionException eex)
    {
        LoggingFactory.GetLogger().Error("PaymentsRepository.GetPendingAndAcquireLock INNER TRANSACTION caught an exception {0}", eex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I have more than 10 thread workers, then this insertion fail occurs too often (75% of queries are failed). It means that I loose 75% of productivity because all my threads are "fighting" for the same payment and only one of them actually gets it.

How to write a query in such way that it always takes the **really available** payment. Maybe, I should use SQL locks on some rows; or change my query so that it gets lock right in the moment of getting the next ID.

Feel free to ask any clarifications concerning this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by utilizing transactions and table hints (locks).

```
while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        var payment = _paymentsRepository.GetNextPendingLock();
        payment = _paymentProcessor.Process(payment);
        _paymentsRepository.Update(payment);
    }
}

public Payment GetNextPendingAndLock()
{
    try 
    {
        string query = @"
      SELECT TOP 1 Id
      FROM [dbo].[Payments] WITH (updlock, readpast)";

        return _dbContext.Payments.SqlQuery(query).Single();
    }
    catch (EntityCommandExecutionException eex)
    {
        LoggingFactory.GetLogger().Error("PaymentsRepository.GetPendingAndLock caught an exception {0}", eex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**updlock** causes the relevant row to be locked and no further reads (*SELECT*) will fetch this row.
**readpast** causes the query to skip locked rows.

[Here's](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/) a nice article describing this method.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Now, up to 30 threads are simultaneously getting distinct non-locked values and process them. Could you, please, make a little clarification. It means that these payments won't appear in `SELECT` results in a moment of their processment. Right?

Comment: That's right. That's the point of the updlock hint. It tells SQL to lock the selected row for the duration of the transaction. When the next attempt is made to select a row for update encounters an already locked row it skips past it due to the readpast hint.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the contention that the competing threads have for the table can be reduced by a redesign:

- Have a single work-dispatching thread (or TPL `Task`) which polls the payments table for new work, in discrete intervals (e.g. via a `System.Threading.Timer`)
- New work is then allocated between N threads to do the actual processing.

The dispatching thread will poll for new work (i.e. awaiting pending / unprocessed payments), and assigns them to an appropriate processing thread. All that is needed to be passed seems to be the `@paymentId` to be processed.

The work can be queued by using to the processing threads / tasks using a dedicated `ConcurrentQueue` per task.

Load balancing can be done as simply as a round-robin allocation by the dispatching thread to the appropriate queue.

The onus of the Sql / DTC / XA transaction boundary would be on the processing thread, i.e. to atomically lock, do the work, and update the incoming record's status.

There would be a small opportunity for a race condition, whereby a task was queued more than once but not yet processed, and hence picked up in a subsequent poll by the work dispatcher. In which case, the processing task / Sql would need to guard against this by adding a check to ensure that the status of the provided transaction was still in a pending status before continuing its work.

This duplication of work would be exacerbated if the concurrent queues started backing up,  so a mechanism to throttle the dispatching thread might need to be introduced if the queue depths became too deep.

This way, you should be able to do away with the custom locking mechanism, and relies instead on well-tested transactional plumbing such as `SqlTransaction`, `TransactionScopes`, or RDBMS transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I see that your solution is architectural and I strongly believe that it is correct. However, I have weighed pros and cons, executed some benchmarks on both methods and preferred another answer because it requires less changes while absolutely suitable for my project with current load. I feel sorry I can't mark both answers as correct :)